# Slim framework configuration outside of Slim

Tags: php, configuration, slim

My Slim project is organised as follows:

```
- app
-- Acme
--- Auth
---- Auth.php (handles authentication)
-- config
--- development.php
--- production.php
-- routes
-- views
- public
- vendor
```

I'm setting up my app in the usual way.

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim([
    'view' => new \Slim\Views\Twig(),
    'mode' => 'development'
]);
```

And injecting dependancies like this.

```
$app->auth = function($app) {
    return new Codecourse\Auth\Auth($app->user);
};
```

What's the most correct way to allow my Auth class to see my configuration? I was originally going to pass it in as a dependancy, but Slim's configuration keys are accessed like `$app->config('key')` so I'd have to pass in `$app`, which would be bad.

I'm aware that my authentication could be served as middleware, but would like to have access to configuration globally.

Would it perhaps be better to use a package like noodlehaus/config (https://github.com/noodlehaus/config) to handle configuration outside of Slim?

Comment: What does your authenticator need from config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you instantiated `Slim\Slim` you can access its instances through the static method [**`Slim\Slim::getInstance()`**](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Application-Names-and-Scopes) from anywhere (e.g. inside your `Auth` class) and then access any of its config properties with the `config('key')` method (i.e. you can use Slim as a resource locator to [get/set really any of the active instance's resources](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Dependency-Injection) from anywhere). And this way there is no need for passing around the application object.

But of course you can always have a separate config object (like the one from the noodlehaus/config package) and use that instead of Slim's built-in resource locator feature ... this way you can access it without instantiating any Slim application objects and have the `Auth` library be independent from the Slim framework.

Comment: I completely missed this, thanks for pointing that out. In the end, I adopted the global configuration using that package, but this will come in handy for future reference. Thank you.